# How to get data from server in ionic

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am out of my depths here in ionic hell. below is my current code which returns an observable. I need it to return the response from the server (it is in a separate file for separation of concerns purposes)

auth.ts

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

export const getToken = function(http){
    let response = http.post('localhost:3000/auth/authenticate', 
                {email: 'mendelh1537@gmail.com', password: 'password'}).then();
    return response();
}
```

home.ts

```
constructor(public events: Events, public http: Http,
    ...

smsPressed(item){
    console.log(getToken(this.http));
}
```

error

```
Error in ./HomePage class HomePage - caused by: __webpack_require__.i(...) is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Http.post` doesn't return a `Promise` it returns an `Observable`

auth.ts

```
export const getToken = function(http){
    return http.post('localhost:3000/auth/authenticate', 
                {email: 'mendelh1537@gmail.com', password: 'password'});
}
```

home.ts

```
constructor(public events: Events, public http: Http,
    ...

smsPressed(item){
    getToken(this.http).subscribe(token => {
         console.log(token);   
    })
}
```